# gulp build fails and npm does not create node_modules

Tags: maven, gulp, node-modules, npm-install

I have a working maven project which I am trying to build but I've got stuck in a failure loop when gulp is running.
Currently the error indicates that no gulp is found inside node_modules directory which makes sense as no directory is created when I run npm install.

```
    [ERROR] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670
    [ERROR]     throw err;
    [ERROR] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\damianakis.LAPTOP- 
    TOSHIBA2\Documents\$INSTALL_DIR\03_app_source\afdbUI\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp'
    [ERROR]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    [ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    [ERROR]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:12)
    [ERROR]     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

I am a newbie and I haven't everything figured out but as far as I know it should be created with the bower.json and the gulpfile which are contained in the project directory (there is no package file ). Here is my gulpfile:

```
const
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'), //rename files
    replace = require('gulp-replace'), //replace text in files
    del = require('del'), //delete files / directories
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'), //autoprefix css for browsers compatibility
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'), //minify css
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'), //validate js files
    // uglify = require('gulp-uglifyes'), //minify js
    terser = require('gulp-terser'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'), //minify images
    rev = require('gulp-rev'), //calculate revision number based on file contents
    gzip = require('gulp-gzip'),
    revRewrite = require('gulp-rev-rewrite'), //replace references of versioned files
    slash = require('gulp-slash'),
    logger = require('gulp-logger'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    ngConfig = require('gulp-ng-config');


const paths = {
    src: {
        base: './src/main/webapp/',
        base_app: 'app/',
        app_subs: 'app/**/',
        scss: 'app/scss/**/',
        js: 'app/js/**/',
        html: 'app/html/**/',
        views: 'app/views/**/',
        assets: 'assets/**/',
        webinf: 'WEB-INF/**/',
        properties: './src/main/resources/**/',
        app_config: 'app/js/config.json'
    },
    manifest: './rev-manifest.json',
    target: {
        base: './src/main/webapp/',
        js: 'dist/js/',
        css: 'dist/css/',
        html: 'dist/html/',
        views: 'dist/views/',
        app_config: 'dist/js/afdb.config.js'
    },

    assets: 'assets',
    webinf: 'WEB-INF',
    layouts: 'layouts',
    pages: 'pages',
    properties: 'properties',
    all_subs: '**/'
};


gulp.task('default', ['build']);

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
    runSequence(
            'build-clean',

            'build-constants-prod',
            'build-views',
            'build-css',
            'build-scripts',
            'rev-rewrite',
            callback
    );
});

gulp.task('build-dev', function(callback) {
    runSequence(
            'build-clean',

            'build-constants-dev',
            'build-views',
            'build-css',
            'build-scripts-dev',
            'rev-rewrite',
            callback
    );
});



gulp.task('build-constants-prod', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.src.base + paths.src.app_config)
            .pipe(ngConfig('afdb.config', { environment: 'env.production'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base + paths.target.js));
});

gulp.task('build-constants-dev', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.src.base + paths.src.app_config)
            .pipe(logger({
                before: 'Logger ==> ngConfig()...',
                after: 'Logger ==> ngConfig() complete!',
                extName: '.js',
                showChange: true
            }))
            .pipe(ngConfig('afdb.config', { environment: 'env.local'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base + paths.target.js));
});


gulp.task('build-css', () =>
    gulp.src([paths.src.base + paths.src.scss + '*.scss'])
        .pipe(logger({
            before: 'Logger ==> sass()...',
            after: 'Logger ==> sass() complete!',
            extName: '.scss',
            showChange: true
        }))
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        // .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base + paths.target.css))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(slash())
        .pipe(logger({
            before: 'Logger ==> css rev()...',
            after: 'Logger ==> css rev() complete!',
            extName: '.css',
            showChange: true
        }))
        .pipe(rev())
        // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        // .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base + paths.target.css))
        .pipe(
                rev.manifest(paths.target.base +  paths.manifest, {
                    merge: true, // merge with the existing manifest (if one exists)
                    base: paths.target.base
                })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base))
);

gulp.task('build-scripts',  () => {

    let manifest = gulp.src(paths.target.base + paths.manifest);

    return gulp.src([paths.src.base + paths.src.js + '*.js'])
            .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
            .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
            .pipe(logger({
                before: 'Logger ==> PROD scripts rev()...',
                after: 'Logger ==> PROD scripts rev() complete!',
                extName: '.js',
                showChange: true
            }))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(terser())
            .pipe(revRewrite({manifest: manifest}))
            // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base + paths.target.js))
            .pipe(
                    rev.manifest(paths.target.base + paths.manifest, {
                        merge: true, // merge with the existing manifest (if one exists)
                        base: paths.target.base
                    })
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base));
});

/**
 * Don't minify
 */
gulp.task('build-scripts-dev',  () => {

    let manifest = gulp.src(paths.target.base + paths.manifest);

    return gulp.src([paths.src.base + paths.src.js + '*.js'])
            .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
            .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
            .pipe(logger({
                before: 'Logger ==> DEV scripts rev()...',
                after: 'Logger ==> DEV scripts rev() complete!',
                extName: '.js',
                showChange: true
            }))
            .pipe(rev())
            // .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(revRewrite({manifest: manifest}))
            // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base + paths.target.js))
            .pipe(
                    rev.manifest(paths.target.base + paths.manifest, {
                        merge: true, // merge with the existing manifest (if one exists)
                        base: paths.target.base
                    })
            )
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base));
});


gulp.task('build-views',  () =>
        gulp.src([paths.src.base + paths.src.views + paths.all_subs + '*.pug'])
                .pipe(logger({
                    before: 'Logger ==> Starting pug...',
                    after: 'Logger ==> pug complete!',
                    extName: '.pug',
                    showChange: true
                }))
                .pipe(pug()) // pipe to pug plugin
                .pipe(logger({
                    before: 'Logger ==> views rev()...',
                    after: 'Logger ==> views rev() complete!',
                    extName: '.pug',
                    showChange: true
                }))
                .pipe(rev())

                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base + paths.target.views))
                .pipe(
                        rev.manifest(paths.target.base + paths.manifest, {
                            merge: true, // merge with the existing manifest (if one exists)
                            base: paths.target.base
                        })
                )
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base))
);


//clean up destination folder
gulp.task('build-clean', () =>
     del([
            paths.target.base + paths.target.css + '**/*.css',
            paths.target.base + paths.target.js,
            paths.target.base + paths.target.views,
            paths.target.base + paths.manifest
    ], {
        force: true
    })
);


gulp.task('rev-rewrite', () => {
    let manifest = gulp.src(paths.target.base + paths.manifest);
    // console.log(paths.target.base + paths.manifest);
    // console.log('manifest', manifest);

    // return gulp.src('./src/main/webapp/app/html/index.html')
    // return gulp.src( [ paths.src.base + paths.src.html, paths.target.base + paths.target.js], { base: paths.target.base} )
    return gulp.src( [ paths.src.base + paths.src.html, paths.target.base + paths.target.js])
            .pipe(logger({
                before: 'Logger ==> Starting rewrite...',
                after: 'Logger ==> rewrite complete!',
                showChange: true
            }))
            .pipe(revRewrite({manifest: manifest}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.target.base))
});

gulp.task('rev-rewrite-index', () => {
    let manifest = gulp.src(paths.target.base + paths.manifest);
    // console.log(paths.target.base + paths.manifest);
    // console.log('manifest', manifest);

    // return gulp.src('./src/main/webapp/app/html/index.html')
    return gulp.src( paths.src.base + paths.src.html)
            .pipe(logger({
                before: 'Logger ==> Starting rewrite index...',
                after: 'Logger ==> rewrite index complete!',
                extName: '.html',
                showChange: true
            }))
            .pipe(revRewrite({manifest: manifest}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/main/webapp/'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {

    // Watch .css files
    gulp.watch(paths.src.base + paths.src.scss + '*.scss', ['build-dev']);

    // Watch .js files
    gulp.watch(paths.src.base + paths.src.js + '*.js', ['build-dev']);

    // Watch .pug files
    gulp.watch(paths.src.base + paths.src.views + '*.pug', ['build-dev']);

    // Watch index.html
    gulp.watch(paths.src.base + 'app/html/index.html', ['rev-rewrite']);

    // Watch embed.html
    gulp.watch(paths.src.base + 'app/html/embed.html', ['rev-rewrite']);

    /*
        // Watch template .html files
        gulp.watch(paths.src_app_subs + '*.html', ['build']);

        // Watch image files
        gulp.watch(paths.src_images, ['build']);
    */

});
```

And here is my pom file which fails at gulp build execution.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <parent>
            <artifactId>afdbMaster</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.primecognition.afdb</groupId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <relativePath>../afdbMaster/pom.xml</relativePath>
        </parent>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <artifactId>afdbUI</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <properties>
            <jetty.server.version>9.4.8.v20171121</jetty.server.version>
            
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.server.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>v11.15.0</nodeVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm config</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>config set cache node_npm_cache --global</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <!--<execution>-->
                            <!--<id>bower install</id>-->
                            <!--<goals>-->
                                <!--<goal>bower</goal>-->
                            <!--</goals>-->
                            <!--<configuration>-->
                                <!--<arguments>install</arguments>-->
                            <!--</configuration>-->
                        <!--</execution>-->
                        <execution>
                            <id>gulp build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>gulp</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>


    </project>
```

I have installed node v11.15.0 which the project requires, npm 6.7.0 and gulp 2.3.0 which I know ran at my coworker's ubuntu environment. I have windows 10 though I don't know if that creates an issue.

Also, when I run npm install I get these warnings prompting me to upgrade. I tried that as well, upgrading to gulp 4, but I had a hard time converting my gulpfile, so I changed it back to older versions.

npm WARN gulp-autoprefixer@8.0.0 requires a peer of gulp@>=4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN gulp-imagemin@7.1.0 requires a peer of gulp@>=4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN Documents No description
npm WARN Documents No repository field. npm WARN Documents No license field.

Any guesses on what could be the issue and how I could possibly fix it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp should be installed as dev dependencies since your maven project is only running npm install.
So at the root of your project (where you can find the package.json), `run npm i gulp@3.9.1`
This will install and add the gulp module into your dev depedencies that can be viewed in your package.json. Next time anyone use your repos, it should work as well now that npm install will also install gulp module.